# A simple Cron job on frontend servers and no backends. Fails

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, frontend, backend, jobs

I configured a simple cron job available at secure(admin only) path `/cron?method=sendMail` to send an email once daily. The servlet at the endpoint of the url is a `jsp` file which has the code to send the email.

This is tested through the frontend with the full url and it works.

I do not have any backend servers configured. Only frontend instances with 1 resident and dynamics.

The issue is that `cron` triggers successfully but the request fails with the following message.

> 0.1.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2013:01:07:44 -0800] "GET /cron?method=sendMail HTTP/1.1" 503 364 - "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)"

This request is getting retried continuously and keeps failing.

The complete url however works. What is wrong with the setup? what am I missing?

Also, how do I stop the retries?

The `cron` entry I use goes like

```
<cron>
    <url>/cron?method=sendMail</url>
    <description>Send mail</description>
    <schedule>every mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun 11:30</schedule>
    <timezone>Asia/Calcutta</timezone>
</cron>
```

Comment: what is the cron entry you are using?

Comment: @ansh0l `<cron>
        <url>/cron?method=sendMail</url>
        <description>Send mail</description>
        <schedule>every mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun 11:30</schedule>
        <timezone>Asia/Calcutta</timezone>
    </cron>`

Comment: From this line of yours, `available at secure(admin only) path`, will it work without authentication?

Comment: @ansh01 cron works if I remove the security, then how do I secure the URL now its open to the public!

Comment: OK Fixed. The issue was with authentication as nudged by @ansh01

Comment: Used the following tip from the documentation to secure the url. Requests from the Cron Service will also contain a HTTP header:

X-AppEngine-Cron: true

The X-AppEngine-Cron header is set internally by Google App Engine. If your request handler finds this header it can trust that the request is a cron request. If the header is present in an external user request to your app, it is stripped.

Comment: Cool then, you should post your findings as an answer, or I can do that as well, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved using the following tip from the documentation to secure the url

> Requests from the Cron Service will also contain a HTTP header: `X-AppEngine-Cron: true`

The `X-AppEngine-Cron header` is set internally by Google App Engine. If your request handler finds this header it can trust that the request is a cron request. If the header is present in an external user request to your app, it is stripped.